# Constraint on table with dates overlapping enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a constraint on table using a user-defined function
in such a way that (`yyyy-mm-dd`) format

| rationid | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-10 |
| 1 | 2022-02-11 | 2022-02-20 |

The second row belongs to same ration id but user should not allowed insert any date between  2022-01-01 to 2022-02-01 in second row, the second row startdate should be after firstrow enddate like 2022-02-02

I tried like this, its working, but if we try to insert the second row startdate same as firstrow enddate its allowing to insert

```
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.MAXRation as m
WHERE m.rationid = @rationid
  AND CONVERT(date, @EndDate, 101) > CONVERT(date, m.startdate, 101)
  AND CONVERT(date, m.endate, 101) > CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 101) 
GROUP BY m.rationid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: If you are correctly using a datetime datatype you don't care about the format, because its not stored in any particular display format.

Comment: Best not to use conversion functions, instead use start and end datetimes

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this. If there is an output, the input dates are wrong.

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM dbo.MAXRation as m
WHERE m.rationid = @rationid
    AND (CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, m.startdate, 101) AND CONVERT(date, m.endate, 101)
        OR CONVERT(date, @EndDate, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, m.startdate, 101) AND CONVERT(date, m.endate, 101)
        OR CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 101) < CONVERT(date, m.endate, 101)
        )
```

If you have the possibility to create a trigger, you can do this control using `LAG()` in the trigger